# Set variable to array in Escape Velocity

Tags: arrays, velocity

I'm trying to set a variable to an array in Escape Velocity like they do in [the documentation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#set):

```
#set ($my = "blah")
#set ($say = ["not", $my, "fault"])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: An error occurred in the @AutoProtoModel processor while processing com.google.protobuf.contrib.autoprotomodel.prototype.AlbumModel:
  com.google.escapevelocity.ParseException: Expected an expression, on line 46, at text starting: ["not", $my, "fault"...
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseException(Parser.java:1093)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parsePrimary(Parser.java:923)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseUnaryExpression(Parser.java:890)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseExpression(Parser.java:797)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseSet(Parser.java:401)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:328)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseNode(Parser.java:218)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parseTokens(Parser.java:126)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Parser.parse(Parser.java:118)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Template.parseFrom(Template.java:112)
    com.google.escapevelocity.Template.parseFrom(Template.java:94)
    com.google.protobuf.contrib.autoprotomodel.prototype.BackingClassGenerator.loadTemplate(BackingClassGenerator.java:97)
...
```

Why doesn't this work?

Is this a bug in the [Escape Velocity project](https://github.com/google/escapevelocity/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  [Escape Velocity](https://github.com/google/escapevelocity) doesn't support to set Java array (from docs):

> Unlike Velocity, EscapeVelocity does not allow $indexme to be a Java array.

Why not using Velocity? EscapeVelocity uses old version 1.7 instead of new 2.0, and you have extra tools for velocity

> EscapeVelocity is a templating engine that can be used from Java. It is a reimplementation of a subset of functionality from Apache Velocity.
>
> This is not an official Google product.